# Sweep length and FFT time

Tags: fft, frequency, measurement, sweep

I'm trying to figure out what length of linear sine sweep I need to cover 100Hz to 9KHz at 1Hz frequency resolution. The max sweep length of my software is 160s, so for this bandwidth it sweeps 55.625Hz/s. Based on the required frequency resolution each FFT will take 1s. Does this mean that I need to split my sweep into segments such that each bin can be resolved properly?

Comment: What's your sampling frequency? What are you using this linear sweep for?

Comment: @Jdip - whatever will allow me to determine frequency components of up to 9KHz - accounting for limitation of the filters - so ~24KHz. The sweep will be played through a speaker to test the response of a microphone

Comment: Why a linear sweep? Pretty much all measuring systems for this type of thing use log sweeps or pseudo random noise that's pink (-ish).

Comment: I'm not deconvolving to get an impulse response, so don't need to use an exponential sweep.